# Decrypt PDF with for loop

Tags: python, pdf, encryption

I am trying to run a for loop that scans lines of a txt and attempts to decrypt a PDF on every line. When it hits the right word, it should break and stop the loop. Here is my code. Please help.

```
import PyPDF2
dictionary = open('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Final Supporting Files\\dictionary.txt')
readDictionary = dictionary.readlines()
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(
    open('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Final Supporting Files\\encryptedhackme.pdf', 'rb'))
for line in readDictionary:
    print(f'Do not stop the program, testing {line}')

    if pdfReader.decrypt(line) == 1:
        print(pdfReader.getPage(0))
        break
    elif pdfReader.decrypt(line.lower()) == 1:
        print(pdfReader.getPage(0))
        break
    elif pdfReader.decrypt(line.title()) == 1:
        print(pdfReader.getPage(0))
        break
```

When I run this code, it is giving me an error that the line variable is an ordinal not in range. It returns an error message at the first line and I truly do not know why it is not working. I double checked and there doesn't seem to be any problem with the dictionary.txt file, it is many lines of words in plain text. Is there any insight as to why it isn't working?

Here is the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Pycharm Projects\Final\PDF_Hacker.py", line 44, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Pycharm Projects\Final\PDF_Hacker.py", line 5, in main
    hack()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Pycharm Projects\Final\PDF_Hacker.py", line 31, in hack
    if pdfReader.decrypt(key) == 1:
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1987, in decrypt
    return self._decrypt(password)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 2017, in _decrypt
    val = utils.RC4_encrypt(new_key, val)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\utils.py", line 181, in RC4_encrypt
    retval += b_(chr(ord_(plaintext[x]) ^ t))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\utils.py", line 238, in b_
    r = s.encode('latin-1')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u014a' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Comment: @jps I updated with that information. This is my first post so please let me know if there is anything else I need to add

Comment: Please add the full error message into your question as text.

Comment: @balmy I added it!

Comment: What is the value and length of `line` When this happens?

Comment: @balmy line contains the word on the line that is currently being read. it is a word in standard text that is usually between 3-6 letters long

Comment: Yes, of course, but what is the actual value and actual length of `line` when it actually fails? Have you checked the documentation or source code of the `decrypt()` function to see what it does when deryption fails because of the wrong key/password? Does it raise an exception?

Comment: @balmy It does not raise an exception. it returns 1 when correct and 0 when not. on the first iteration the value is 'AARUS' len 5

Comment: Have you tried this with a pdf you’ve encrypted/know the password for, using both the correct and an incorrect password to see what results you get? I.e. does it work at all?

Comment: @balmy I did, without the loop and hard coding the password into it, it decrypts just fine. I am trying to make a brute force code here that tests all words in a massive dictionary. I know what the password is and setting it to a word I know is in the dictionary isnt helping

Comment: Are you sure you’re using the latest version of PyPDF2? Line 2017 in pdf.py looks different in source on github.com. Do pip install -U PyPDF2

Comment: There’s some sort of encoding problem - have you checked that dictionary.txt is in fact ascii? I think you can see this in e.g. Notepad++ open it and encoding is shown on bottom bar of the notepad++ window.

Comment: @balmy it says that it is encoded with UTF-8. is this correct for this program?

Comment: Ah. Try converting it to ascii or latin-1, think Notepad++ can do that - sorry not at laptop so can’t say what the actual menu is, it’s either on the edit or view menu. Not saying that’s definitely the problem but the exception is about not being to encode a unicode character.

Comment: @balmy I changed it and it shows up on notepadd++ but the same file opened in regular notepad is still using utf8.

Comment: Try making a new file by e.g. copy con >dictionary.txt type a couple of words one/line then control-z and see if it works better. Otherwise I’m clean out of ideas apart from the pip update to latest PyPDF2.